# Proof that the area of a region in the plane is unchanged under shearing transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

My Geometry book (Lang's Geometry 2nd edition) presents the following two theorems concerning shearing transformations without proof:

> 1. The area of a region in the plane is unchanged under shearing
>      transformations.
> 2. The volume of a region in 3-space is unchanged under shearing
>      transformations.

I would like to know how these results can be proved. The book defines area and volume to be the amount of space enclosed by a 2/3-dimensional figure, expressed in unit squares and cubes respectively. As to what a "shearing transformation" is, it simply states that it's a "stretching in some direction", so you are free to pick the definition you find best suited to the proof. Thanks.

Comment: Could you define the shearing transformations as matrices, and use the determinant $=\pm1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping

Comment: See [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to prove it would be geometrically.

All a shear mapping is is a way to transform a rectangle into a parallelogram.

[image: Shear transformation diagram from Wikipedia]

As you learned in elementary school, a parallelogram with a given vertical and horizontal extent (base and height) has the same area as a rectangle with the same base and height, because you can just chop them up and rearrange them into one another.

[image: Parallelogram transformed to rectangle by cutting and moving an edge]

This simple argument can be extended to any number of dimensions, and any combination of shear transforms in any direction.

---

The second, somewhat more rigorous way to prove it would be to use **determinants**, as @David-Quinn suggested. (If you don't know much linalg yet, a matrix is a way to transform space, and the determinant of a matrix represents how much the space is scaled during the transformation -- that is how much area/volume is lost or gained)

A shear matrix in 2D looks like this, which stretches space across the x-axis by a value $\lambda$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \lambda \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Or this, which stretches spaces across the y-axis by a value $\lambda$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\lambda & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant of a 2D matrix is:

$$\begin{vmatrix} a & b\\c & d \end{vmatrix}=ad - bc$$

Substituting in our values gets us:

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} 1 & \lambda \text{ or } 0\\0 \text{ or } \lambda & 1 \end{vmatrix} & =1\cdot1 - \lambda\cdot0\\
\\& = 1\end{align}$$

Since our determinant is one, space has been scaled by exactly one, and therefore the area/volume of the space has not changed. This works pretty much the same in 3D, but taking the determinant of a 3D matrix is a long and painful procedure, so I'm not writing that one out.